# WCF DataServices + Silverlight + Entity Framework CodeFirst model object is null

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, wcf-data-services, odata, silverlight-5.0

I have a WCF DataService with the following CodeFirst models:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }   
    public string LastName { get; set; }   
}
```

I also have the standard supporting classes `SchedulerContext`, `SchedulerContextInitializer`, and `SchedulerService.svc`.  My service looks like:

```
public class SchedulerService : DataService<ObjectContext>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
    }

    protected override ObjectContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        var ctx = new SchedulerContext();
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;
        return objectContext;
    }
}
```

I added the Service Reference to my Silverlight project just fine.  I can browse the service in my browser and see my seed data.  When I go to `http://localhost:31560/SchedulerService.svc/Projects(1)/Owner`, I can see my seed data.  However, when my projects load in my Silverlight data access class:

```
public class SchedulerService : ISchedulerService
{
    public SchedulerService()
    {
        var context = new SchedulerContext(new Uri("/SchedulerService.svc",   UriKind.Relative));

        this.Projects = new DataServiceCollection<Project>();
        DataServiceQuery<Product> query = context.Projects;
        this.Projects.LoadAsync(query);
    }

    public DataServiceCollection<Project> Projects { get; private set; }
}
```

Each project's Owner is **always** null!  How do I fix this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
context.Projects.Expand("Owner");
```

Comment: That was it, thanks!  If anyone's interested, I also found a way to avoid "magic strings" with [ODataMuscle](http://elegantcode.com/2010/10/17/odatas-dataservicequery-and-removing-the-expandmagicstrings-part-ii/).